# PHP or Java to handle long running background requests

Tags: php, ajax, multithreading

This is a design question and I appreciate your insight / advise. I understand this question may have different answers based on experience and I am merely trying to seek some guidance before I make a selection on how I proceed.

Background -
My application is primarily built on LAMP stack - Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP. I also use jQuery to client side scripting and the application is fairly simple and executes very fast. I am also using CakePHP framework

Scenario #1 -

1. The user clicks a link on the web page
2. The click triggers an AJAX call to a PHP script on the server
3. The PHP script make a cURL request to another web address to process some information and usually returns in 4-5 seconds
4. Upon return the PHP script completes execution and terminates

Question -

1. I keep hearing that PHP is synchronous and will hang until this request is finished - so if multiple users make multiple requests in the above scenario will PHP hang until each request is processed sequentially or does Apache take care of spawning multiple threads to process each web request separately?
2. I am trying to figure out a way to better handle this - even if it means I should step outside of PHP. Would you recommend I use PERL scripting to handle to cURL request and just have PHP fork a shell thread and exit or would it be better to create a JAVA servlet that the AJAX can call since JAVA is multi-threaded it can handle this on the same.
3. I am reading up on pThreads - is this a scenario where pThreads would be

Scenario 2

1. User uploads a zip file and clicks the process button and then quits the application
2. Upon clicking the process button an AJAX request is sent to the server to process the zip file. The PHP script receiving this request has `ignore_user_abort` enabled so it does execute even if the user quits.
3. However processing of this zip file can take multiple minutes as it involves multiple cURL calls and SOAP calls across web servers
4. Once processing is done, the PHP script updates the database and terminates

Question

1. Again similar to the above question, is this something that will be blocking in nature if multiple people upload files at the same time?
2. Assuming PHP would queue all the various requests - would this cause a timeout scenario and loss of requests?
3. Is this something better done with PERL/JAVA etc?

Thank you for your advise and insight

Comment: 1# its jut like 10 visitors hilting your index.php at the same time - they don't have to wait for each other

Comment: 2# ajax call process.php which runs `exec(proc2.php >>)` it will run forever in he background doing its ting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is

**Scenario #1**

1. all / most languages are synchronous, that said running ajax is asynchronous and by extension running php by ajax is asynchronous.  The thing is here you are confusing "synchronous" which in this context means block until an operation is finished or process blocking, with parallel processing or even multi-threading.
2. again multi-threading is quite different then parallel processing, php is quite capable of running dozens of parallel processes.  Is it the best language for it, probably not but it can do it with as little effort as running a shell script with exec and a command like this  `exec(usr/bin/php -f pathtophpfile/index.php arg1  > /dev/null & );` on linux.  multi-threading is defined as this:

> Multithreading is the ability of a program or an operating system process
>   to manage its use by more than one user at a time and to even manage
>   multiple requests by the same user without having to have multiple
>   copies of the programming running in the computer

Parallel processing is defined as this

> Parallel processing is the simultaneous use of more than one CPU or
>   processor core to execute a program or multiple computational threads.

So while technically php cant do either of these, you can run multiple copies of php at the same time on the same machine, much in the same way as you can manually open multiple shell windows and run commands in each of them.  Is it parallel processing or multi-threading?  No, it's just running multiple copies of PHP at the same time.

3. But the biggest challenge with any " multi-threaded or parallel process " is race conditions.  If you are careful to avoid them you will be fine.  Race conditions are like this

   - process1 loads text.txt
   - process1 makes changes
   - process2 loads text.txt - before process1 has saved its data
   - process2 makes changes
   - process2 saves changes
   - process1 saves changes

Now you will lose any changes made by process2 because process1 had the data in memory and never accounted for process2 changing it.  This is also what I would call a concurrency issue, they are basically the same thing.  Another thing to look out for if using CRON or some other rudimentary queuing method, is not pulling the same job with multiple processes.

Also debugging can be a challenge, this is true of any background process and not specific to php.  The simplest thing to do here is use a file to log your output to using things like `ob_start()` & `$var = ob_get_clean()` ( output buffering) and recording that.  It's also useful to use a shutdown handler to log errors such as

http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

Of course these are over simplified examples, explanations but that is the gist of it.

**Scenario #2**

1. how would it be? as I mentioned php and Apache can serve over 200 clients at once, another request is just another connection to Apache ( when using ajax or CURL ) but its basically the same even when just using the CLI (command line interface).  There is no inherent reason you cant run several dozen php processes at once.
2. How would it Queue it, they just execute again like oping multiple tabs in a browser.  As for a timeout, there are always resource limits on a server no matter what language you use.  You could use a queuing system to insure that only a few files are processed at a give time, this could be as simple as cron and a database table with some status column, such as queued, running, complete.  then the cron script runs one job marked as queued, marks it as running while running, marks it complete when done, rinse and repeat.
3. That is a matter of opinion and more so a matter of your ability with those languages.

I'm actually building a system in php that takes one csv file and breaks it into 25000 row chunks ( without re-writing separate files, just reading from offsets in the same file with multiple threads ). These chunks are then processed in parallel by up to 10 workers and then aggregated back together, and then some reports and emails ect are generated. Is it easy to do, no.  Is it possible, sure is.

The system I am building for example takes a file with say 1million + rows, and queries a database with over 700k records. It works a bit like this

Job Preprocess  ( one process creates multiple chunks )

1. create a job file
2. calculate ofsets
3. queue ( in rabbitMq ) multiple jobs

Process  ( multiple processes each handle one or more chunk )

1. load data from queue
2. access input_file.csv at offset and read to end of offset
3. generate a numbered result file such as 0.csv, 1.csv for each chunk

Aggregation  ( one process only, receives the bits of the job )

1. load previously saved job file ( from step 1 )
2. as each chunk completes record that in job file
3. when all chunks are done, compact all the results from the numbered files in order.

The trick here is that the multiple process part ( step 2 ) doesn't touch that job file in step one ( or it would encounter race conditions ), further only one process receives all of the chunks for a job.  Once all the chunks are received, we compact them into one file do some clean up and then send out emails etc..

With this I have ran a file with 1 million rows in under 2 minutes.  Using a single thread / process it takes about 15 minutes to run the same file.

So ( again ) I assure you It can be done, it's tricky and you have to be very careful on how you move your data around but it's not impossible to do these things in php.  PHP and modern hardware for that matter can handle thousands of operations a second.  Usually the bottle necks are bad indexing in a database or waiting on network connections ect...

If you plan on doing some real heavy duty work I'd suggest looking into a queuing or messaging system like I use ( RabbitMq ) but that might be overkill in your case.  I use the queuing system to help keep the process flow sane and avoid race conditions, basically it's sole purpose for me is to organize the data flow.

Comment: Thanks - very insightful. I will accept if I dont see any better responses. Two follow on questions - if I understood the race condition you mentioned, it will come into play if two requests are trying to modify the same content or file. In my instance, each request will be modifying a different database record so the chances of race condition are minimal if I am correct - does this make sense?

Comment: Second follow on question - if a PHP script is executed by AJAX (as described in Scenario 2) and the PHP script makes cURL requests for each content of the zip file - is there a general timeout limit? I mean lets say there are 100 files within the zip file and each file take 60 seconds to process - will the PHP script stop processing the zip file after 10 files or will it continue until all 100 are done regardless of how long they take?

Comment: For the fist one that is correct.  For the second there is a script execution time limit, and a memory limit both can be changed at run time with set_time_limit() and ini_set('memory_limit', {value such as 256MB}), or you can set them in the php.ini file.  Curl has its own timeout that can also be set.

Answer (score 1):

### Scenario #1

- 1) PHP is synchronous, but the question is confused. PHP executes instructions synchronously, normally, however Apache defines the processing model. Apache will reuse or spawn a worker process or thread to handle the request, up to the configured limit.
- 2) The way you are handling it is fine, you might want to try and reduce the amount of time it takes to update the user interface, because 4-5 seconds is rather long.
- 3) I will talk a little about using threads at the frontend.

Using threads at the frontend doesn't make sense. As mentioned, your webserver has a defined processing model, it is designed to scale with that model, creating user threads as the result of a web request disrupts that model. Even if user code creates a reasonable number of threads, for example 8, if 100 clients come along at once, you will be asking your hardware to execute 800 threads concurrently.

*That is clearly a bad idea !*

### Scenario #2

- 1) The same answer as #1.1, it's the processing model of the server that handles multiple clients.
- 2) The same answer as question 1 in both scenarios.
- 3) That's entirely a matter of opinion.

The problem you seem to have is essentially the same in both scenarios.

### Advice

Don't make anything more complex than it has to be; in both scenarios, the problem is your receiving server side code responds slower than is desirable.

In the case where you have many HTTP requests to make to process a request, your code is I/O bound, don't go straight to multi-processing or multi-threading at all, try non-blocking I/O first, this is simpler, more accessible, more suitable, and scales with PHP.

In the case where you have code that is CPU bound, for example, you have solved the I/O problem, and are making all your requests using non-blocking I/O, but once data is downloaded, it requires considerable processing to be used. Then you might think about using multiple processes or threads.

Whatever happens, you should not use multi-threading at the frontend, what you want to do is isolate those parts of the application that require multi-threading and communicate with this isolated sub-application using some sane form of RPC.

Comment: Thank you - was hoping you would respond. I have been reading a lot of your articles / responses lately. So as a follow on question - when should we use threads and when should we not? And lastly - any pointers on what you mean by non-blocking IO? My problem is that the cURL requests I am calling are outside my control and take extra time to respond - so am trying to do this in such a manner that it doesn't create a huge queue of requests and secondly it doesn't cause timeout issuea

Comment: Use threads when you have too; when all other options have been explored and exploited. You will have to read up on NBIO, support is built into PHP in various forms, most popular form is probably cURL Multi.